# What's the best way to handle multiple SKScenes?

Tags: ios, sprite-kit, skscene

I made a game using the default new game project and then inserted a normal UIView as the app intro scene. I'vs since 'upgraded' the intro into using an SKScene, with buttons that push the original gameViewController onto the stack. It seemed a bit laggy once the gameview was loaded so I'm assuming that's to do with the overhead of having 2 full skscenes and view controllers. I even set the landing scene to pause, but it will obviously still use memory!

My question is, how can I use an SKScene as the landing page (with it's own LandingViewController) and then efficiently add the GameViewController to the stack. I've tried merging the 2 view controllers, but this seems like a stupid way of doing things.

Current setup:

```
LandingViewController
|-LandingScene

GameViewController
|- GameViewScene
|- Other Game Classes
```

App enters at LandingViewController which inits the LandingScene (and landing UI Sprites). LandingViewController handles the touch events like buttons etc. When new game is tapped, GameViewController is pushed (currently using a Segue) and GameViewController inits it's scene, gamestate, UI, game board etc. GameViewController handles it's touch events for it's scene. When a game ends (click end game or game over state) the GameViewController is popped.

Both LandingViewController and GameViewController control the flow of their animations and clicks etc, so GameViewController does the game logic, like next turn end game etc.
Any help or pointers would be appreciated as I would like to do this right!

Comment: hmm could you specify what is lagging on you?  Using large amounts of memory will not cause lag unless you are constantly releasing and renewing resources, so you may have something else going on that you are not aware of.

Comment: The sprites I am moving on the GameScene are slower to react and animate. This only started once I had the 2 views with scenes. I'm no reworking the function based on the suggestions of @Whirlwind

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Having a Single View Controller and Multiple Scenes**

You could use single view controller (which is actually a default state of SpriteKit game template) and have multiple scenes.

So you will have `GameViewController` and `LandingScene`, `GameScene` and possible some other scenes, like `LevelSelect` scene or something like that.

In `GameViewController`, you initialize your scene for the first time. So that is the point where you initialize your `LandingScene` (I guess that is the place where you implemented your navigation menu).

So, from that point, you are able to make a transition from any scene you want using `SKView's` [presentScene:](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKView/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/SKView/presentScene:) method (and optionally using `SKTransition` class).

**Transitioning**

Transition in `SpriteKit` can be generally done in two different ways:

**1.** Some might tell you that making a transition from a current scene, to the next scene is a "bad design" and that the current scene should notify the view controller about its ready-to-transition state, so that view controller can make needed transition. But in response to that, these are quotes from docs:

> **Transitioning Between Two Scenes**
>
> Typically, you transition to a new scene based on gameplay or user
>   input. For example, **if the user presses a button in your main menu
>   scene, you might transition to a new scene** to configure the match the
>   player wants to play.

And the related code:

```
- (void)mouseUp:(NSEvent *)theEvent
{
    [self runAction: self.buttonPressAnimation];
    SKTransition *reveal = [SKTransition revealWithDirection:SKTransitionDirectionDown duration:1.0];
    GameConfigScene *newScene = [[GameConfigScene alloc] initWithSize: CGSizeMake(1024,768)]];
    [self.scene.view presentScene: newScene transition: reveal];
}
```

It can be clearly seen that transition to the next scene is done within current scene.

**2.** Using the method described above using delegation pattern, where scene delegates responsibility of transitioning  to the view controller.

Both ways are perfectly fine, where the first method is a bit convenient IMO, and widely used. So that is how you can navigate between different scenes in `SpriteKit` in an easy way.

**Hint:**

Don't forget to override scene's `dealloc` (or `deinit` if you use Swift) method while in development phase, to make sure that all scenes are deallocated correctly.

Comment: Thanks. I'm going to try to rework what I have to have a UIViewcontroller in charge and then switch out the scenes. I just need to move all the functions into each scene as needed.

Comment: Ok so I went with option 1 and it worked perfectly! Thank you so much. I'll probably end up moving to 2 and using delegates in the end as it makes sense to keep it all in the scenes with as little in the containing viewcontroller as possible

Comment: Boy, I became concerned when I used your approach in switching SKScene = several SKScenes, 1 GameViewController. It worked and Thanks! **But**, here’s the rub = **rotation**. Specifically, If the Simulator is preset to Portrait, my SKScene is sized correctly .. and ditto if preset to Landscape. But, not after rotation-in-place. I’ve overridden **didRotate** to call **presentScene** again on the rotated SKScene but with no luck. Do you have some spare smarts to address this rotation sizing  issue? Again it rotates, but is not resized.