# In SpriteKit presentScene Transition, won't work. However, presentScene does

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

```
let reveal = SKTransition.doorwayWithDuration(0.5)
            reveal.pausesIncomingScene = false
            reveal.pausesOutgoingScene = true
              //self.skView!.presentScene(self.gameOverMenu!, transition: reveal)
            self.skView!.presentScene(self.gameOverMenu)
```

That is the portion of code I'm using to present the new scene. The skView already has a scene running, I'm doing this from the view controller. When I do present scene it all works fine. But when I try to add the transition the new scene never shows up. The transition property of the view updates and so does the incoming and outgoing scene property. Any ideas?

Edit:
It seems to be an issue with segueing from another VC to the current VC. If I remove my original landing VC and start the app at the VC that has the spritekit view, everything works normally. Now to either redesign how I am doing things, or figure out why moving to a new VC makes transitions stop working.

Comment: At which point a method holding this code is invoked ?

Comment: When contact begins between two physics bodies. I’ve also presented an empty scene and had that scene attempt to do a transition and it fails in the same way.

Comment: You should add more context from your current setup to completely describe how everything works... What you are trying right now, works for me if I run this code directly from within didBeginContact (when contact occurs). So, I guess there is something wrong with the rest of your code. It is unclear a bit how you notify view controller to make a transition (you said this is the code from the view controller, but then you said you are running this when contact occurs). I guess you are using some kind of delegation, but it would be easier to debug if you post the whole setup...

Comment: And when I say "works", I mean works with transition... Also, you may consider to switch between multiple scenes in this way : http://stackoverflow.com/a/35409586/3402095

Comment: I have gotten it down to not be an issue with the scenes themselves, since like I said I made some blank scenes and can’t get them to transition either. Which leads me to think it is something to do over the view or view controller. I star with one view controller then when the user wants to play I morally present another which has the scenes. I am using a delegate to send data to the view controller to transition to the new scene. I have also tried transitioning from the scene itself with no luck. I wonder if modally presentation the VC is causing an issue, I’ll try using one VC.

Comment: It should be noted that the VC is running the method just nothing happens. if I use just present scene it works fine. And like I said the current scene updates it’s transition and out and in scene properties.

Comment: exactly the same problem!