# How can you connect a swift file with an SKscene?

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

I looked through all posts, WWDC talks and youtube videos, but I still can't figure out how to have multiple SKscenes for different levels and connecting them with swift files in a Game using Spritekit. I want to have a main level board and I managed to open a new scene if you press a SKSpriteNode, but how can I implement game logic to this specific SKScene?
Apologies in advance if it is a silly question, I've been spending ages on it.

Comment: Do you want to launch a new SKScene from the one you are currently in?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do it like this:

**1) Create `.swift` file and make a subclass of a `SKScene`**

Go to :

> File menu -> New File -> Source -> Swift file

and make subclass of a SKScene

```
class MenuScene:SKScene {}
```

**2) Create .sks file**

Then go to

> File menu -> New File -> Resource -> SpriteKit Scene

and make a `MenuScene.sks` (name it `MenuScene` without the actual extension).

Repeat this steps for each scene you want to have.

Then to load and start your initial scene. Do this inside your `GameViewController.swift`:

```
if let scene = GameScene(fileNamed:"GameScene") {
      let skView = self.view as! SKView
      //setup your scene here
      skView.presentScene(scene)
}
```

To make a transition to other scene (lets assume that you are in the `MenuScene` currently) you should do something like this:

```
if let nextScene = GameScene(fileNamed: "GameScene"){
  nextScene.scaleMode = self.scaleMode                 
  let transition = SKTransition.fadeWithDuration(1)                  
  view?.presentScene(nextScene, transition: transition)
}
```

Comment: As an addition, read more here about having multiple scenes in a SpriteKit project. http://stackoverflow.com/a/35409586/3402095

Comment: Your post was very helpful I got it working now I also have read through  the other post  what you have linked  that was also very helpful thank you  very much for that good answer!