# How can I dismiss a ViewController from my GameScene.swift?

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, sprite-kit

**QUESTION:** How can I dismiss a ViewController from my GameScene.swift ?

---

**SITUTATION:** I have 2 VCs in my SpriteKit Game, like so:

ViewController.swift ----Press Play----->  GameViewController

When the player loses, I want to dismiss the GameViewController so the player can press play again. I check for the player's loss in my GameScene.swift and would like to dismiss the GameVC from there.

---

**N.B.:** Googled this without success.

---

**WHAT I TRIED:**

1) Creating a gameVC instance in my GameScene.swift and dismissing it like so:

```
let gameVC = GameViewController()
gameVC.dismissViewController(false,completion: nil)
```

2) Doing:

`self.view.window!.rootViewController?.dismissViewControllerAnimated(false, completion: nil)`

Those don't work for obvious reasons ^^

Comment: 1) won't work: you need to use the *existing* instance, not a new one. 2) will only work if `self.view.window!.rootViewController?` is your `GameViewController` instance, but it looks like that's probably a `ViewController`.

Comment: @AaronBrager Yes I know :) That's why I put this in the "What I tried" section. I just don't see how to grab the existing instance :/

Comment: You need to either hand `GameScene` a reference to the view controller so it can dismiss it, or use the delegate pattern to communicate backwards to a controlling object that the VC should be dismissed/dismiss itself

Comment: @AaronBrager Put this in answer so I can accept it (if it works) :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't want to "grab" the existing instance: https://pragprog.com/articles/tell-dont-ask

You need to either hand `GameScene` a reference to the view controller so it can dismiss it, or use the delegate pattern to communicate backwards to a controlling object that the VC should be dismissed/dismiss itself.

A simple example… you can add a `GameViewController` property to `GameScene`, then dismiss the VC at the appropriate time:

```
class GameScene: SKScene {
    var gameVC: GameViewController?

    func gameDidEnd() {
        gameVC?.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true) {
            // if desired, do any cleanup after the VC is dismissed
        }
    }
}
```

Then, just set this property when creating the `GameScene` object in the first place:

```
if let gameScene = GameScene(fileNamed: "MyScene") {
    gameScene.gameVC = someGameVC
}
```

This simple approach will tightly couple `GameScene` and `GameViewController`, making it a bit more difficult if you ever want to use one of these objects without the other. But for this simple use case, it may be fine.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but SO is against link only answers because they can become invalid. Could you please add a code snippet so I can accept your answer and upvote it? :)

Comment: Sure, I'm happy to. One sec

Comment: I have a memory leak now after trying this :/

Comment: Can you elaborate?

Comment: Each time I lose (dismiss GameVC, therefore get back to mainVC where there is the play button) and play again, the FPS drop.

Comment: Seems like you might have a strong reference cycle. You could try `weak var gameVC` if so.

Comment: That was it! Thx ! (Maybe edit your answer with `weak` also ?)

Comment: Don't think I should edit my answer — `weak` is only necessary because of the strong reference cycle but that is not required by either your question or my answer.

Comment: Ok, I wonder where I created that strong reference cycle :/ I alway take extra care to avoid them but it eluded me this time it seems >:)

Comment: Maybe your view controller has a strong reference to the scene?

Comment: You may consider using one view controller & multiple scenes approach. http://stackoverflow.com/a/35409586

Answer (score 1):

I've follow some of your discussion. I want to add some code, because usually I prefeer to work with one ViewController or two and many SKScene and SKNode, but in this case could be useful to have a **currentViewController** reference:

```
class MyModelScene: SKScene {
   let appDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
   var currentViewController : MyModelViewController! = MyModelViewController() 
 // MyModelViewController is a customized UIViewController

   override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {
      super.didMoveToView(view)
      print("---")
      print("∙ \(NSStringFromClass(self.dynamicType))")
      print("---")
   }
}

class Level1Scene: MyModelScene {
    ...
}
```

In the `UIViewController`:

```
class PreloadViewController: MyModelViewController {
     override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        if let scene = Level1Scene(fileNamed:"Level1Scene") {
            // Configure the view.
            let skView = self.view as! SKView
            skView.showsFPS = true
            skView.showsPhysics = true
            skView.showsNodeCount = true

            skView.ignoresSiblingOrder = true

            /* Set the scale mode to scale to fit the window */
            scene.scaleMode = .ResizeFill 
            scene.currentViewController = self
            skView.presentScene(scene)
        }
    }
}
```

With this code , you've always a currentViewController reference in your `SKScene` and you can check if it's the correct viewController you want to dismiss or not.

Comment: You don't need `NSStringFromClass`; all Swift types can be converted to strings.

Comment: Nice man, thank you , I had not even noticed because comes from my old code +1