# dismiss SKScene go back to UIKit Menu

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, skscene

Once my SpriteKit game has ended, I would like to go back to my `UIKit MenuViewController`. From what I've learned so far, using ***protocol/delegate*** is the best(?) option, but I haven't been able to get that to work. I know that the protocol would probably go above the class declaration for `GameViewController`, and look something like:

```
protocol GameViewControllerDelegate {
    var gameOver: Bool?
}
```

But I need help accessing that from `GameScene` AND getting it to dismiss `GameViewController`. Below are the bones of the app, in case that helps.

[image: storyboard image]

**MenuViewController**

```
class MenuViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    @IBAction func goToGame(_ sender: UIButton) {
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "toGameSegue", sender: sender.currentTitle)
    }

    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if let destinationVC = segue.destination as? GameViewController {
            if let item = sender as? String {
                destinationVC.numberOfPlayers = item
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**GameViewController**

```
class GameViewController: UIViewController {

    var numberOfPlayers: String?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        if let view = self.view as! SKView? {
            if let scene = SKScene(fileNamed: "GameScene") {
                scene.scaleMode = .aspectFill

                scene.userData = NSMutableDictionary()
                scene.userData?.setObject(numberOfPlayers!, forKey: "numberOfPlayers" as NSCopying)

                view.presentScene(scene)
            }
        }
    }
...
```

**GameScene**

```
class GameScene: SKScene {

    var howManyPlayers: String?

    override func didMove(to view: SKView) {

        if let numPlayers = self.userData?.value(forKey: "numberOfPlayers") {
            howManyPlayers = numPlayers as? String
        }

        print(howManyPlayers!)

    }
...
```

This SpriteKit game has a MenuViewController, a GameViewController, and a GameScene. When you press a button from MenuViewController, data is sent via segue to GameViewController. Before GameViewController presents GameScene it stores the data in scene's userData variable so that GameScene can access it. In this example, it's the number of players.

Comment: What you are doing IMO is unnecessary mixing of UIKit with SpriteKit. It will work of course if you do something like in Alessandro's answer, and I can't say that you shouldn't do it, but this would be a preferred way : http://stackoverflow.com/a/35409586/3402095 I say preferred, because this is what can be seen in Apple's demo games so far.

Comment: Absolutely - mixing UIKit and SpriteKit is more complicated than I had imagined. My thinking was that I'm pretty comfortable with constraints and I need quite a few buttons so why not? Now I know.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I agree with Whirwind comment's: why mixing two different frameworks and complicate your life when you can use one viewController only to do all your game?

Anyway, according to your storyboard screenshot,there are 2 viewControllers and you can go to the second viewController (and to the `GameScene`) **only if you press a button**.

There are two things to do: deallocate the current SKScene (in your case the `GameScene`) and present the "initial view controller" or your `MenuViewController`.

To do it, I use the *"Hello world"* Sprite-kit template with a *protocol/delegate* approach to extend the `SKSceneDelegate` [class](https://developer.apple.com/reference/spritekit/skscenedelegate). As you can see we able to dismiss the scene (presenting nil) and call an external method on the `GameViewController` to present the `MainViewController`

To be sure that both of these operations go to be successful I use also two `print` just for debug:

### **GameViewController**:

```
import UIKit
import SpriteKit
class GameViewController: UIViewController,TransitionDelegate {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        if let view = self.view as! SKView? {
            if let scene = SKScene(fileNamed: "GameScene") {
                scene.scaleMode = .aspectFill
                scene.delegate = self as TransitionDelegate
                view.presentScene(scene)
            }
            view.ignoresSiblingOrder = true
            view.showsFPS = true
            view.showsNodeCount = true
        }
    }
    func returnToMainMenu(){
        let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
        guard  let storyboard = appDelegate.window?.rootViewController?.storyboard else { return }
        if let vc = storyboard.instantiateInitialViewController() {
            print("go to main menu")
            self.present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
    }
}
```

### **GameScene**:

```
import SpriteKit
protocol TransitionDelegate: SKSceneDelegate {
    func returnToMainMenu()
}
class GameScene: SKScene {
    override func didMove(to view: SKView) {
        self.run(SKAction.wait(forDuration: 2),completion:{[unowned self] in
            guard let delegate = self.delegate else { return }
            self.view?.presentScene(nil)
            (delegate as! TransitionDelegate).returnToMainMenu()
        })
    }
    deinit {
        print("\n THE SCENE \((type(of: self))) WAS REMOVED FROM MEMORY (DEINIT) \n")
    }
}
```

**Output**:

[image]