# SCNAction.playAudio causes crash when nodes get deinitialized

Tags: ios, swift, scenekit

We pinpointed the cause of the crash to the statement of using `SCNAction.playAudio` in our game. If any `playAudio` statements get called in our game, the deinitialization of the SCNScene/SCNView would later randomly trigger this crash:

[image]

How we play the audio:

```
func playAudioSource(from node: SCNNode, source audioSource: SCNAudioSource) {
    node.runAction(SCNAction.playAudio(audioSource, waitForCompletion: false))
}
```

It shows the `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` being at `CPP3DAudioEngine::RemoveContext`. We're developing for iOS 10.3 using SceneKit and Swift 3.

Comment: Try turning on zombie objects, which might make it easier to pinpoint the object being deinitialized.

Comment: zombie objects, malloc logging all couldn't point the problem

Comment: Hmm…I'm not sure what the issue is then. You do mention that it crashes randomly; is this a set amount of time after playing audio?

Comment: as long as I run the `node.runAction` statement, the game crashes when the view controller of the scene deinits. The zombie objects, malloc loggings showed nothing

Comment: Inspect the threads of all the method calls related to the node/playing audio, maybe this will be a clue.

Answer (score 5):

You should provide more code to better understand what happen in your game but surely you can correct your function with:

```
func playAudioSource(from node: SCNNode, source audioSource: SCNAudioSource) {
    if let _ = node.parent, node.action(forKey: "playAudio") == nil {
        node.runAction(SCNAction.playAudio(audioSource, waitForCompletion: false),forKey:"playAudio")
    }
}
```

This prevents the launch of the action when the action it's already launched or in execution and check also if your node is already attached to it's parent (this can be useful, it depend from where you launch this code..)

Comment: doesn't fix. I either play audio on the rootNode of the scene or on specific nodes within the scene. most are non-positional. It seems that CPP3DAudioEngine is trying to remove context, but it's already been removed.

Comment: Try to add more code, especially the part where you launch this playAudioSource , where exactly you do it because CPP3DAudioEngine removeContext only in specific situations..

Comment: the scenario is as such: the game logic plays one sound (running `playAudioSource` once) on the root node of scene after the `SCNScene` gets loaded. The sound is less than 1s. Then after about 15s, I leave the game and the viewcontroller along with everything gets deinit. After a very short moment the `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` gets thrown

Comment: Are you sure your scene is deallocated correctly? Try to print something to the `deinit` method to see if your scene is removed. How do you make this deallocation in term of code? Take a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43336790/dismiss-skscene-go-back-to-uikit-menu/43339122#43339122) to a similar transition maded to Sprite-kit to see if you really respect the deallocation time of your scene and the transition to the UIKit viewControllers. Hope it helps