# When to use UIViewControllers and Scenes for a SpriteKit game

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, sprite-kit, skscene

I'm writing a small game in swift and getting a little bogged down with navigating between **UIViewControllers** from an **SKScene**.

I'd like to have a **MainMenuViewController**, from which the user can access settings or start the game. If the game is started the **GameViewController** is presented which holds the **GameScene**. Once the game is over i'd like to navigate back to the **MainMenuViewController**, However, I am struggling to do so from within the **GameScene**.

*QUESTION:

What is the convention with using multiple UIViewControllers here (specifically within games), i.e. should I be creating **MainMenuScene** and have everything contained within one **UIViewController**. Or is there a simple way of moving between **UIViewControllers** from within an **SKScene**?*

I ask because from my research, doing latter seems more complicated than I would expect and I'm worried I'm overcomplicating things!

Here is my most recent attempt, called on **gameOver** in **GameScene**:

```
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
let mainMenuViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "MainMenuViewController") as? MainMenuViewController
self.gameViewController.present(mainMenuViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Comment: Forget multiple controllers for now. They are not really needed most of the time. Take a look at this : https://stackoverflow.com/a/35409586

Comment: I concur with Whirlwind.  Explore one of the sample games made by Apple.

Comment: You should just make a "Game" from the new project screen. It's much easier to just use the GameViewController