# SKScene View Controller not deleting after exit

Tags: objective-c, sprite-kit, skscene

I am a novice programmer in the process of developing an IOS app, and I have run into a problem - after exiting the game using a storyboard segue, the sound effects continue playing in the background, leading me to believe that it has not been deleted. These sound effects continue even if I start a new game. After starting several games, the FPS drops significantly, backing up my hypothesis.

Does anyone know why the game is still playing after exit, and what I can do to solve the issue? I am using a modal segue triggered by the push of a button. Please post any code in Objective-C, as I am useless at translating between languages. Thanks!

Comment: Without code, and your app structure, people can guess. Add additional info, and somebody will point to the issue. Your sound manager or sound player is not deallocated from some reason , possibly that some other object (a scene, or a view?) is retaining it. Or simply, you forgot to stop the sound. Also, can you describe why do you have to use segues for transitioning rather tha SKTransitions (can you describe your app structure)?

Comment: If I'm honest, I had never heard about SKTransitions before your comment. After looking them up, they seem to be the right thing for me to use - after the game has finished the app is supposed to transfer to an information screen giving the user information about their game and offering to restart or return to the main menu. Is this problem likely to persist if I use SKTransitions instead of segues? Also, I am sure that it is not simply a sound player/manager deletion issue as I am not using one - I play sound effects as actions on the SKScene.

Comment: SKTransitions are meant to be used for transitioning between scenes...So yeah, they could be right thing for you. I would say that you have multiple view controllers...If so, I would recommend [having single view controller and multiple scenes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35409586/3402095). Now back to the sound issues. It is likely that you haven't properly stopped the action , plus the scene that plays it is never released. Possibly strong reference cycle. You should show the code that plays the action.

Comment: Also, in the scene that plays the sound, put this `deinit { print("Scene deinited"}` or if you use Obj-C, then put `dealloc { NSLog(@"Scene dealloced");|}` and let me know if those statements are printed after you leave the scene .

Comment: Here is the code for the sound effects:

Comment: SKAction *playPop = [SKAction playSoundFileNamed:@"POP.mp3" waitForCompletion:NO];

Comment: [self runAction:playPop];

Comment: (where 'self' is an SKScene)

Comment: Where shall I put the `dealloc { NSLog(@"Scene dealloced");|} ` in my code?

Comment: You should put dealloc in the scene in which you play sound. Please edit your question in the future when adding the code, rather than pasting it here in the comments...

Comment: By the way, do you repeat somehow this action? How long is the POP.mp3 sound (in seconds?) And please add more context. From the one line of code I cant really say much.

Comment: I do not repeat the action, and it is under 1 second long. Sorry about the code in the comments - I just got an account today and I'm a bit of a noob. I am slightly confused as to what you mean by "in the scene". Do you mean in the function where I play the sound or just anywhere?

Comment: In the scene,  at the same level where `viewDidLoad` instance method is defined. Okay, if that sound is only one second long and not repeating, how can you hear it after the game is over ? You said - "it continues playing..."

Comment: The sound is played whenever the player hits a wall. If the player presses the 'done' button while playing, the sound effect continues playing in the background, so it sounds like this: 'Pop, Pop, Pop...'. This to me suggests that the game is still playing in the background, as the `didBeginContact` method is obviously still running. I came across the problem when I was debugging and I commented out the code that made the player die. This meant that game could keep playing by itself if the scene was exited, rather than just hitting my `GameOver` function and deleting everything.

Comment: I tried the code you told me to and there was nothing printed to the log. I think that essentially my segue is not deleting the view controller/scene. I am using a modal transition: is there another kind of segue that would delete the view controller once it has been exited?

Comment: In these cases, it would be really easier if you just upload the project to the github (if that is an option for you) and I will find what the problem is. Or, you can implement a method that will stop the game actually. eg, reset all scores, stop all actions eg. [self removeAllActions] etc. Still, if that scene is not meant to be alive all the time, then you should find what retaining it, and handle it correctly. But I can't really say what is the problem if I don't see a project or the relevant code.

Comment: Here you can find what causing leaks, and how to solve them : https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html It is a big topic and there was a lot of posts here on So already about that.

Comment: I have implemented an function like that, in which I run these three actions on the scene: `[self removeAllChildren]; [self removeAllActions]; [self removeFromParent];` but it is only called when the player dies, not when the segue is called. The issue is not so much about the sound effects, but more about that the scene is obviously still in the background and using up CPU power. Is there any way that I can make the segue delete the view controller and all of its children after it had been executed? I think that this would be easier and would require less reprogramming if it is possible.

Comment: Maybe I'm getting a little confused. I will read over the page you commented and see if that helps. Thank you so much for all your time and assistance!

Comment: All that mixing UIKit with SpriteKit that you have done, is not needed IMO, and a bit of a wrong way to do things. As far as your UIKit related question, maybe you could try with [unwind segues](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/technotes/tn2298/_index.html) ... There are other ways to achieve the same thing, but because I of insufficient information here, it doesn't make sense for me to comment further on this. And I have spent my SO daily time for today :) Good luck and  please read [how to ask good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Also this pokes my eyes `[self removeFromParent];` That statement doesn't have an effect ;) Scene is root node, and it doesn't have a parent.

Comment: soz ;) thought it might help delete it